# Edit element style in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, element, edit

I have a slider in my WP where pictures get cropped when I resize the window

Here is a picture of a slide when the website is fullscreen and besides is the same slide when I resize the window which we can see is cropped on the right:
[click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IutS.jpg)

(when "inspect element" I can see that element.style section that I didn't manage to find on my css files)

Then on the element inspector I edited the element.style by adding "background-position: center;" and when I resized again the window the picture did exactly what I wanted (it centered as I was resizing):
[click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKb4F.jpg)

As I said I tried to find the css sheet where I could edit that but I learned that it could not be done that way and that I had to force the WP to update by adding css lines

I tried theses:

```
.animate-in[styles] {
    background-position: center !important;
}

.animate-out[styles] {
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

but didn't manage to get anything working...

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't find the css sheet because css was generated with javascript.

You can try :

```
#sequence li {
   background-position: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please at the very least post the url to your webpage so i can play with it. The SS is very low quality.

What you are seeing is known as an inline style, you can overwrite it with the !important tag. The element you are highlighting has an ID that you can target to over write this.

so in your child theme's stylesheet you can write

```
#widget-kopewidget_sequence_slider-2-sequence_slider-item-208 {
background-position:center !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Did exactely what I wanted! as I had to do it for all different slides I went for Pepi solution who worked as well and avoided changing for each slide! Thanks again!